# Multiple ESXi VMs with same base

Tags: virtual-machine, snapshot, esxi

I'm trying to create multiple VMs in ESXi with the same base, to conserve space.

For example, I'd like to create a base VM, with Windows 2008 and SQL 2008.
Then I'll want VM 1 to install software-1 and VM 2 to install software-2.

Assuming the base VM is 10GB, and I have 2 VMs based off that, my savings are 20GB. If I have 4 VMs based off the base VM, the savings would be 40GB.

It'll be a bonus if I can also update the base VM, and have the changes propagate to the other 2 (or 4) VMs.

I've done some googling on base VM, snapshot, etc, but I'm unable to find how to do this, probably due to the wrong terminology being used.

Does anyone know how I can achieve the above, either via GUI or by command line?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the scenario can't be done by ESXi. We do snapshots for backup (of course, saving space) but not for seed.

The scenario may be termed `SANDBOX`. There is an famous open source solution [linuxcontainer (lxc)](https://linuxcontainers.org)

> LXC is a userspace interface for the Linux kernel containment features. 
>   Through a powerful API and simple tools, it lets Linux users easily create 
>   and manage system or application containers.

---

If you want to do that on ESXi, the only way I thought is clone machine. (without saving space and time efficiency). And every time the seed machine update, you need to delete and clone again.

```
=> SEED ---> clone machine A  ---> delete   +---> NEW SEED ---> ...
    |    |                                  | 
    |    +-> clone machine B  ---> delete   |
    |                                       |
    +----------------------------- update --+
```